# Setting UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout Xamarin iOS F#

Tags: ios, f#, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have created an instance of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` as follows:

```
type CollectionViewFlowDelegate (handle:IntPtr) = 
    inherit UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout (handle)

    override x.GetSizeForItem(collectionView : UICollectionView, layout : UICollectionViewLayout, indexPath : NSIndexPath) =
        CGSize(100.0, 300.0)
```

I also have a `UICollectionViewController` defined as follows:

```
[<Register ("LandlordHome")>]
type LandlordHome (handle:IntPtr)  =
    inherit UICollectionViewController (handle)

    let addToList (listan:List<Listing>) (element:Listing) = element::listan

let mutable listings : List<Listing> = List.Empty

override x.ViewDidLoad () =
    base.ViewDidLoad ()
    x.View.BackgroundColor <- UIColor.Gray
    for i in 1..10 do
        let listing : Listing = new Listing(....code....)
        listings <- listing::listings
    x.CollectionView.BackgroundColor <- UIColor.Green
    //x.CollectionView.Delegate <- new CollectionViewFlowDelegate(handle);
    x.CollectionView.RegisterClassForCell(typeof<ChatViewCell>, new NSString("ChatCell")) 


override x.ViewDidAppear(animated) = 
    x.CollectionView.ReloadData()

override x.NumberOfSections(collectionView : UICollectionView) = 
     Conversions.nint(1)

override x.GetItemsCount(collectionView : UICollectionView, section : nint) =
     Conversions.nint(listings.Length)
```

This works fine. However, now I want to set the delegate for the `collectionView` in my `UICollectionViewController` so that the size of the `UICollectionViewCell` is overwritten. To do so, I uncomment this line:

```
 //x.CollectionView.Delegate <- new CollectionViewFlowDelegate(handle);
```

This causes the program to crash here:

```
Conversions.nint(listings.Length)
```

with the following exception:

`System.NullReferenceException has been thrown. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

This doesn't make any sense to me as the code works fine without the delegate being set, so `listings` is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you forgot using `Register` attribute.

```
[<Register ("CollectionViewFlowDelegate")>]
type CollectionViewFlowDelegate (handle:IntPtr) = 
inherit UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout (handle)
```